# Illustrator SVG export Inside Glow effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, svg, export

I'm designing a logo for someone but i got a huge problem.

I've got this paperpress effect (Inside glow):

[image: Logo]

I need to export this to an SVG format
But when i do this and open it in my browser, this happends:

[image: Export].

The effect just doesn't work anymore like it should.

Before this all, i exported the exact same logo WITH a rectangle spanned across the file (Background) and then it worked perfectly. How can the problem occur when i remove the background but doesn't occur when i have a background?

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Things i've tried:

- Fiddle around with the SVG export settings

Kind regards,
Dobbermann2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of quite bombproof SVG. Something resembling is crunched together in Inkscape. No effects are used, only simple paths, fills, strokes, gradients and the normal blending mode:

[image]

The text was outlined and the strokes of the text were lifted above the grey gradient layer.

The SVG file was opened in Firefox browser. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would consider trying to create the desired effect another way, as svg's aren't ideal for (and don't usually support) complex detail and effects.